# Chargebee Failed a load resurce. the server responded with a status of 404()

Tags: chargebee

[image]

**Chargebee**
Failed a load resurce. the server responded with a status of 404()

Comment: How is this related to `javascript` or `node.js`? What is the actual problem here? Is this even programing related?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Settings > Configure Chargebee > Checkout and Self-Serve Portal and enable Checkout.